# How to plot probability histogram in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram, probability

I have a data of pore sizes (in micrometers^2) that are present in the microstructure of material. In total I have 942 pores. I used SciPy in order to load the data.If I plot a histogram with the bins that I created manually, I get histogram like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ueU32.jpg)

It can bee seen that pores with size of approximately 250 micrometers^2 have the highest frequency and thus the highest probability of being present in the microstructure.

Can anyone tell me how to get probability histogram from this, because I need to use Weibull distribution function and fit the curve to histogram.

I tried to add "density = True" in my code but then I get this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6BVs.jpg)

Here is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sci

file1 = 'data_histogram.csv'
file2 = 'data_histogram_1.csv'

data_hist = sci.loadtxt(file1, delimiter=',')
data_hist_1 = sci.loadtxt(file2, delimiter=',')

bins = data_hist[:,0]
data_pores = data_hist_1[:]

plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Times New Roman'

fig1 = plt.figure(1, figsize=(9,8))
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(1,1,1)

ax1.set_xlabel('Pore size', fontsize=14)
ax1.set_ylabel('Freqeuncy', fontsize=14)
ax1.tick_params(direction='out', size=9, width='1.3', labelsize=14)
ax1.hist(data_pores,bins=bins, density=True)

plt.savefig('figure_example1.jpg')
plt.show()enter code here
```

Comment: *"It can bee seen that pores with size of approximately 250 micrometers^2 have the highest frequency and thus the highest probability of being present in the microstructure."* - That claim is not justified. As you can see by the normalized histogram, very small pores have the highest probability. I would recommend to use equally sized bins in order to not misinterprete the results.

Comment: But if we look at the range from 200 to 300 micrometers^2, the pores of that size are  most dominant in the microstructure. That's why I'm confused about this other graph.

Comment: I mean, I don't know your data, but the density plot clearly shows that the smaller pores are more frequent. As said, use equally sized bins, like `bins=20` for both histograms in order to see this more clearly.